# Capture Image AVMetadataFaceObject with didOutputSampleBuffer:

Tags: uiimage, avfoundation, cvpixelbuffer

I am trying to capture the face area.

Here is what I do , in **didOutputMetadataObjects:** is get the AVMetadataFaceObject and process it in **didOutputSampleBuffer**

**didOutputMetadataObjects** shows marker correctly, where I consider the Yaw, roll axis

What could be the best possible way, where I get only the face area and at the same time I see a face marker?

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

   for(AVMetadataObject *metaObject in metadataObjects){
        if([metaObject isKindOfClass:[AVMetadataFaceObject class ]] && metaObject.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeFace){
           AVMetadataFaceObject * adjustedMeta = (AVMetadataFaceObject*)[self.videoLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:metaObject];
           self.metaFaceObject= adjustedMeta;
           //Draw the face marker here
            }
    }
}
```

AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{

CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        if(pixelBuffer ){
            CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments( kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate );
           CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer options:(__bridge NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable)(attachments)];
            ciImage = [ciImage imageByCroppingToRect:self.metaFaceObject.bounds];
            //This Image is upside down. Second thing the it does not have the face.
            UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage];


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## hello some suggests below:

**1:** add a stillImageOutPut

```
lazy var stillImageOutPut: AVCaptureStillImageOutput = {
    let imageOutPut = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.init()
    return imageOutPut
}()
```

**2** add to session

```
if session.canAddOutput(stillImageOutPut){
            session.addOutput(stillImageOutPut)
}
```

**3** then implement this delegate function

```
// MARK: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate

extension ZHFaceDetectorViewController: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    printLog(Thread.current)
    let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first
    if let object = metadataObject {
        while !hasDetectorFace {
            if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.face{
                hasDetectorFace = true
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    if let stillImageConnection = self.stillImageOutPut.connection(with: AVMediaType.video){
                        printLog(stillImageConnection)
                        printLog(connection)
                        stillImageConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue)!
                        /// prepare settings 如果不设置 截取照片时屏幕会闪白
                        let settings = AVCaptureAutoExposureBracketedStillImageSettings.autoExposureSettings(exposureTargetBias: AVCaptureDevice.currentExposureTargetBias)
                        /// begin capture
                        self.stillImageOutPut.prepareToCaptureStillImageBracket(from: stillImageConnection, withSettingsArray: [settings], completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
                            if error == nil {
                                self.stillImageOutPut.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: stillImageConnection, completionHandler: { (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) in
                                    printLog(imageDataSampleBuffer)
                                    printLog(error)
                                    if error == nil {
                                        if let sampleBuffer = imageDataSampleBuffer {
                                            if let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer){
                                                if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                                                    /// operater your image
                                                    printLog(image)
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        printLog("something was wrong")
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        })
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

4 then i get my picture
[log info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvMWs.png)